# Access deep nested object from array

Tags: node.js, json, angular

I am having a challenge getting just the username in a response below. How do I access the username. i can access the other data but this

[
{
"_id": "5f44d450aaa72313549d519f",
"imageTitle": "uuuuu",
"imageDesc": "uuuuu",
"imageControl": "public",
"imageUrl": "http://localhost:3000/uploads/image-1598346320523.jpg",
"userId": {
"local": {
"username": "uuuuu"
},
"_id": "5f44d3e9aaa72313549d519e"
},
"uploadedOn": "2020-08-25T09:05:20.840Z",
"__v": 0
},

{ ....}

]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so

```js
var arr = JSON.parse(`

[ { "_id": "5f44d450aaa72313549d519f", "imageTitle": "uuuuu", "imageDesc": "uuuuu", "imageControl": "public", "imageUrl": "http://localhost:3000/uploads/image-1598346320523.jpg", "userId": { "local": { "username": "uuuuu" }, "_id": "5f44d3e9aaa72313549d519e" }, "uploadedOn": "2020-08-25T09:05:20.840Z", "__v": 0 },

{}

]`);
console.log(arr[0].userId.local.username);
```

If you are on a newer version of node (14.0.0, and up), then I recommend using the optional chaining operator

```js
arr[0].userId?.local?.username
```

Comment: Thanks but i am trying to use *ngFor to fetch each imageUrl and the username of the user.